# How to change only part of filename during renaming a lot of files

Tags: mercurial, file-rename

I have a lot of files like:

```
Post - something_is_here1.rb
.
.
Post - something_is_here100.rb
```

I'd want to rename them to:

```
Article - something_is_here1.rb
.
.
Article - something_is_here100.rb
```

I don't want to `hg rename` each file maually. How can I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do this with just Mercurial.

Instead, you could use a small shell script:

```
for f in Post*; do
    hg mv "$f" "Article${f#Post}"
done
```

Alternatively, you could rename the file some other way, then use `hg addremove`, which will detect the renames if the files are identical.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do it in Mercurial, but you can perform it with any external tool and in one Mercurial command without shell-script

- Rename files, using needed pattern, with any 3-party tools
- Apply to Working copy `hg addremove --similarity 100` (-s|--similarity will detect *pure rename* from step 1)